# Use of 'antinomic'

Tags: contradiction

ANTINOMY – a contradiction between two beliefs or conclusions that are, in themselves, reasonable.

I HAVE TO to use the word 'antinomy' (or 'antinomic') in a sentence to convey the following meaning:

> **X is contradictory to Y.**

Can I say: **"X is antinomic to Y"**?  Perhaps a different preposition should be used?

Comment: You'll occasionally see *X is antinomic **with** Y*, but I think that's probably mostly down to conflation with closely-related usages such as *X is **incompatible** with Y*. Usually, the preposition here would be ***to***.

Comment: I am translating something and the author uses antinomy in the original. I hoped that maybe there is a way to transfer it to English... If there isn't, I will write "X is contradictory to", of course.

Comment: *X is antinomic to Y* is correct. As you noted, you can say *X is contradictory to Y* — same preposition.

Comment: If you have used *antinomy* and its derivatives elsewhere in the same translation, then you are right in wanting to use some version of it here, but it might be better to say something like 'X and Y constitute an antinomy'. *Antinomic* is rarely used in English, although its intended meaning would be readily recognised by those who are familiar with *antinomy*.